# .gitignore exclusion not working

Tags: github, gitignore, github-for-windows

I am using GitHub for Windows to commit files. My `.gitignore` looks like:

```
bin/*
!bin/IncludeThis.dll
```

I want to only include this binary, and not any others in any `bin` directories. However, this pattern is including all files in the `App/bin/` directory (including the one I want).

If I change it to:

```
bin/
!bin/IncludeThis.dll
```

Then the whole `App/bin/` directory is excluded (as expected). Any suggestions? Is this a bug in Github for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using, in addition of G4W (GitHub for Windows), a recent version of [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.io/), don't forget you can see [why a file is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168102/6309)!

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/bin/IncludeThis.dll
```

Try, [with msysgit 1.8.4](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount), a `.gitignore` directly in the right bin folder to start debugging this (remove the other `.gitignore` files).