# Git ignoring podfile when gitignore doesn't mention it

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, gitignore

My gitignore file says nothing about podfiles. In fact, I can make it empty, and still get the same result - my 'Podfile' is being ignored. If i change it's name to something different, it sees it, but otherwise just ignores it. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

There's a nifty little utility called [`check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore.html)* that serves *exactly* this purpose. **Example use:**

```
git check-ignore -vn path/to/Podfile
```

It'll output the file, line number and pattern that makes git exclude the file.

<sub>* ***fun trivia***: check-ignore was born right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168102/3080396) at Stack Overflow. So go forth and thank Adam Spiers!  (-:</sub>