# A way to validate .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a way to validate a .gitignore file so you quickly find doubles paths or paths that don't exist anymore? Normally when a project is small this isn't really necessary but with lots of branches and mergings of .gitignore files this can come in hand.

Answer (score 28):

Not exactly.
One command which could come close would be [git check-ignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)

Choose a file you know is supposed to be ignored, and check the output of:

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/ignored/file
```

You will see the rules of your `.gitignore` which apply.

---

Update March 2016: Git 2.8 will add a new way to debug `.gitignore` files and their rules.

In the context of allowing a sub-folder to *not* be ignored (even if its parent folder is ignored: see [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606460/6309)), I have found [this gem](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bac65a2be598811d944c846bdf61580f5c1af927) by [Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds):

> ### `dir.c`: support tracing exclude

[`man git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bac65a2be598811d944c846bdf61580f5c1af927/Documentation/git.txt#L1067-L1070) includes:

```
GIT_TRACE_EXCLUDE:
```

> Enables trace messages that can help debugging `.gitignore` processing.
> [See '`GIT_TRACE`'](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bac65a2be598811d944c846bdf61580f5c1af927/Documentation/git.txt#L1006-L1012) for available trace output options.

With `GIT_TRACE_EXCLUDE` set to 1, you will see (after a `git status`) [stderr debug messages like](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bac65a2be598811d944c846bdf61580f5c1af927/dir.c#L910):

```
exclude: from ...
exclude: xxx => n/a
exclude: xxx vs. yyy at line z: => www
```

---

But [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) (Merge branch 'nd/exclusion-regression-fix', 2016-02-24, Git v2.8.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56f37fda511e1615dc6df86c68f3b841711a7828)) was reverted, reversing changes made to [e79112d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e79112d21024beb997951381db21a70b087d459d) (Merge branch 'ce/https-public-key-pinning', 2016-02-24, Git v2.8.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e79112d21024beb997951381db21a70b087d459d) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56f37fda511e1615dc6df86c68f3b841711a7828)).

We will be postponing nd/exclusion-regression-fix topic to a later cycle.

<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5cee349](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415), 18 Mar 2016)</sup>

> ### [`5cee349370`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415):Revert "Merge branch 'nd/exclusion-regression-fix'"

Comment: Sadly, it looks like `GIT_TRACE_EXCLUDE` was reverted shortly after that commit added it: https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415 . I didn't dig into why it was removed, just tracked this down while trying to understand why the flag wasn't doing anything in git 2.43

Comment: @GrantG True, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a script to check it. I have made one for you there:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o noglob
for file in `cat .gitignore | grep -v \#`
do
    printf "$file"
    find . -name "$file" | wc -l
done
```

it will display the rules followed by the number of match in the current directory and recursively. Example:

```
*.log     31
*.gz      0
*~     42
*.swp      0
*.aux     33
*.pdf     51
*.out      7
*.toc      6
*.nav      1
*.snm      1
.DS_Store      0
```

You could restrict the output to the line containing `0` by piping into `egrep "\b0\b"` if you want.

Comment: This assumes `find`'s globbing matches git's `.gitignore` globbing. Is that a safe assumption?

Comment: To be fair, I haven't check. I also rarely use the fancy things like negation or double *. It should work just fine for the standard * wildcard though.

Answer (score 1):

In order to also validate git's ** pattern in paths I had to write a one-liner inspired by the script above:

```
find . -type f | git check-ignore -v --stdin | perl -pe 's,.*\.gitignore:,,; s,\t," "x100,e' | sort | uniq -w 100 -c | perl -pe 's, {100}.*,,'
```

Not exactly pretty but it works.