# git, ignore files with a pattern in Laravel

Tags: git, laravel, gitignore

I have this .gitignore file:

```
/node_modules
/public/storage
/public/hot
/storage/*.key
/vendor
.idea
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
.project
/nbproject
_ide_helper.php
composer.phar
error.log
Todo.rtf
.vagrant
/.vagrant
npm-debug.log
.env
/public/css/backend.css
/public/css/frontend.css
/public/js/backend.js
/public/js/frontend.js
/public/mix-manifest.json
/public/mix.js
```

Right now I'm ignoring last lines (starting with `/public/...`) but they are specific files. In my project I have a lot of compiled files like:

```
/public/css/backend.345346n345jkn3454.css
/public/css/frontend.679nkj67n9n79n679.css
/public/js/backend.2345b34j5bn345m34..js
/public/js/frontend.234234234n234f.js
/public/mix-manifest.json
/public/mix.9b87a1da741f957f3f09.js
```

Etc... so I want to include all the files that has the "backend", "frontend" and "mix" text in the beginning of the name. It is possible to do something like this?:

```
/public/css/backend*.css
/public/css/frontend*.css
/public/js/backend*.js
/public/js/frontend*.js
/public/mix*.js
```

I did that but it doesn't work, so I don't know how to do it.

EDIT: This question is not about ignoring already commited files on a repository. I wanted to know the use of wildcards for my specific situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: It is not, because the question was "It is possible to do something like this?:" about the use of wildcards *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup. You can use this syntax in you `.gitignore`. Probably you are trying to ignore something that is already committed, though.

To untrack a *single* file that has already been added/initialized to your repository, *i.e.*, stop tracking the file but not delete it from your system use: `git rm --cached filename`

To untrack *every* file that is now in your `.gitignore`:

**First commit any outstanding code changes**, and then, run this command:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

This removes any changed files from the *index*(staging area), then just run:

```
git add .
```

Commit it:

```
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

---

To undo `git rm --cached filename`, use `git add filename`.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908151/a-way-to-validate-gitignore-file).

Comment: Yes, they are already commited, I will read that, thanks. Anyway, you are not answering my question about the * on file names.