# Why does Git ignore these folders?

Tags: git, git-status

I added a Laravel App under Git so that I could push to Bitbucket. On root folder, I ran `git add -A` and pushed on remote server. I checked that it did not send all folders; for instance, it did not add `vendor` folder at all. How do I make sure that all subfolders are added? When I run `git status`, it says:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**Update**

I ran `git status --ignore` and found the following files listed:

```
stocktrack/app/storage/logs/laravel.log
stocktrack/app/storage/meta/services.json
stocktrack/app/storage/sessions/cdf664ccf42d040bc92d76418f736cc78e20d77a
stocktrack/app/storage/views/81774cd762e1fa0174ad42e0b0d53196
stocktrack/bootstrap/compiled.php
stocktrack/composer.lock
stocktrack/vendor/
```

In `.gitignore`, I only added `.idea`. Why did it ignore the others?

Comment: Note: `GIT_TRACE_EXCLUDE=1 git status` will soon (git 2.8, March 2016) be an additional way to debug `.gitignore` rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953923/6309

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to determine if a path is getting ignored by git.

Furthermore `check-ignore` offers a `-v` (`--verbose`) option which will tell you about the pattern that ignores your file and where you can find it.

---

Let's assume you have a repository with the following directory structure.

```
bar/test/important
foo/a.tmp
foo/b
```

And this `.gitignore` file.

```
bar/
foo/*.tmp
```

You wonder why your `important` file in `bar/test/` is getting ignored.

*This is a pretty bland example, but it just serves to show the concept.*

Now let's check which pattern ignores your `important` file.

```
$ git check-ignore --verbose bar/test/important
.gitignore:1:bar/       bar/test/important
```

As you can see, `check-ignore` tells you that the pattern `bar/` in your `.gitignore` file on line 1 ignores the path in question.

Answer (score 5):

`git add --force <Specific Folder>` did the trick with me.

Comment: That's merely a treatment of the symptoms. It makes more sense to solve the problem at it's root. Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600789/2274224).

Comment: This isn't a permanent solution.  Problem will re-occur on the next branch.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I had, and most likely you had is that **.git/info/exclude** had these folders listed in it.  I had to remove them from there.  Then I ran:

1. `git rm -r -f --cached .`
2. `git add .`

Answer (score -1):

It seems `.gitignore` works.

Check your repository's root directory. You will find a file .gitignore which includes file names to be ignored.

Comment: Updated Question. gitIgnore does not have required pattern

Comment: You might have global gitignore http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335420/global-git-ignore