# Check which commited files can be .gitignore'd now

Tags: git, gitignore

Is possible I check which commited files can be .gitignore'd now? For instance, I commited `a.tmp` in an old commit, but now I create a rule like `*.tmp` on `.gitignore` and I like to untrack this old files. I like to know which files are this and how I can untrack it.

Comment: Note: `GIT_TRACE_EXCLUDE=1 git status` will soon (git 2.8, March 2016) be an additional way to debug `.gitignore` rules. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18953923/6309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`git check-ignore --no-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to do this.  Here's a small demonstration.

```
$ git init foo
cd fInitialized empty Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.git/
$ cd foo
$ touch a.tmp
$ git add a.tmp
$ git ci -a
[master (root-commit) 30f7de9] Add a.tmp
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.tmp
$ echo '*.tmp' > .gitignore 
$ cat .gitignore 
*.tmp
$ git check-ignore --no-index *
a.tmp
```

If you want to do the whole repository, `find . -type f | xargs git check-ignore` (I forget how to make find skip the .git directory).