# Including specific file extension in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to include all the *.meta files in the Assets directory and all subdirectories while excluding everything else in Assets

I tried

```
/Assets/*
!/Assets/**/*.meta
!*.meta
```

but that only include *.meta within /Assets ????

Thanks for any help

Comment: You want to exclude all *.meta files from git?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if an ignore rule does not work, you can check this [with `git check-ignore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953923/6309):

```
git check-ignore -v -- yourFile
```

It will display which ignore rule ignore a file that you thought should not be ignored.

Then the main rule to remember when it comes to ignore is:

> [**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309) (`*`)
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.?+, see below)

That is why your rules only include `*.meta` within `/Assets` (and not the subdirectories)

You would need to include all parent folders of a file (as [in this recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956527/6309)) in order to include a file

```
/Assets/**/**
! /Assets/**/
!/Assets/**/*.meta
```

I tested it with git 2.4.1 and it works (even on Windows).
It does include only the `*.meta` files in `Assets` and all subdirectories, but exclude everything else.

---

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

However, since one of the condition to re-inclusion was:

> The directory part in the re-include rules must be literal (i.e. no wildcards)

That would not have worked here.

Comment: Thanks VonC - The problem is that I don't know the names of all the subfolders in Assets and they change all the time.  :-(  I would like to include only the *.meta files in Assets and all subdirectories, but exclude everything else

Comment: @OptimisticMonkey can you try with `!/Assets/**/` before `!*.meta`. Maybe that would include all subfolders, before including meta files.

Comment: `/Assets/*
!/Assets/**/**.meta
!/Assets/**/
!*.meta`  results in all files being included in Assets

Comment: @OptimisticMonkey No: `!/Assets/**/` As I said, you need to include the subfolders in order to include files. That is mentioned in my answer: **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**

Comment: How do I exclude all the other files except *.meta that are included now? Sorry - just can't seem to figure it out - always includes all files or only *.meta in the first directory

Comment: @OptimisticMonkey Try my edited answer: I just tested it and it works: it does include only the `*.meta` files in `Assets` and all subdirectories, but exclude everything else.

Comment: Thanks VonC (Sorry it took long to reply - the comment was not showing)  I tried the edited /Assets/**/**
! /Assets/**/
!/Assets/**/*.meta and it still doesnt include any .meta in nested subdirectories :-(

Comment: @OptimisticMonkey can you do a `git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/a/file.meta`?

Comment: @OptimisticMonkey Well done! You can accept the answer then if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks VonC Answer Accepted :-)