# Gitignore exclude certain files in all subdirectories

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory called /static. There is a lot of subdirectories in it.
I need to ignore all files in all subdirectories of the /static/ directory except of .htaccess, null.jpg and index.php files.
Tell me please what is the right syntax for this operation?

```
/static/**
!/static/**/.htaccess
```

and

```
/static/*
!/static/*/.htaccess
```

don't work.

Comment: I think you should whitelist the directories first. Does `!/static/**/` work as second line in your first approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Including specific file extension in gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30390221/6309)", the main rule to remember is:

> [**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. (`*`)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.?+, see below)

That is why any rule which ignores folders (like `*` or `*/`) would make excluding any sub-files impossible.

That is why the right approach is to exclude everything except:

- folders,
- (*then*) the files you want to exclude.

If you don't exclude folders first, your files would still be ignored (because of the rule I mention above)

So add in your `.gitignore`:

```
/static/**/**
!/static/**/
!.gitignore
!.htaccess
```

This is tested with Git 2.4.1 and works even on Windows.

---

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

However, since one of the conditions was "The directory part in the re-include rules must be literal (i.e. no wildcards)", you cannot use that feature here anyway.