# Gitignore all except one folder and all its content - regardless of the nesting level

Tags: git, gitignore

I know that this question has been asked many times, but honestly - in spite of many accepted answers, I've not found a neat solution to this problem. I stress the work **neat** here.

I want to ignore everything except one folder and its **entire** contents.

This will not achieve it:

```
*
!dest
!dest/*
```

that would preserve the `dest` folder and all files that are in `dest`, but not other folders within in as well as files in these sub-folders.

Somebody wrote in comments! to one of similar questions that you cannot achieve this without specifying full paths to what you don't want to ignore if you start your `.gitignore` with `*`.

I am now convinced that he was right. Or is there a **neat** way to ignore  everything except one folder and its **entire** content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested (with a recent Git, [even on Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

```
*
!dest/
!dest/**
```

As usual, you just have to follow the rule:

> **[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. (`*`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)**
>   (`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.?+, see below)

Once the `dest` folder is white-listed (`!dest/`), you can exclude its content (on multiple levels) easily (`!dest/**`).

From there, any `git check-ignore -v dest/x/y/z/aFile` would return nothing, which means `aFile` be added.

I mentioned a similar principle (slightly different solution) in "[Gitignore exclude certain files in all subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30476326/6309)".

---

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

Here, this should work with git 2.9+:

```
*
!dest
```