# gitignore all content in a folder except a folder with all its content

Tags: git, gitignore

I am working with Grav CMS with this folder structure (simplified):

```
/user/
  /pages/
  /plugins/
    /admin/
    /devtools/
    /google-photos/
    .gitkeep
```

and this `.gitignore` file:

```
/user/plugins
!.gitkeep
!/user/plugins/google-photos/
```

I want to ignore all files and folders (with subfolders) in `/user/plugins` except all `.gitkeep` files. This works so far. But now I would like to include a single plugin in git (google-photos) with all its content. I tried this, but it didn't work: `!/user/plugins/google-photos/`

How can I do this?

I already visited these, but they couldn't help:

- [.gitignore ignore all files then recursively allow *.foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024924/gitignore-ignore-all-files-then-recursively-allow-foo/8025106#8025106)
- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)
- [Gitignore all except one folder and all its content - regardless of the nesting level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792426/gitignore-all-except-one-folder-and-all-its-content-regardless-of-the-nesting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `/user/plugins` folder is ignored, then any exception below that folder will be ignored.

That is because:

The general rule is:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)**

To exclude files/folders from /user/plugins (whose content is ignored), you would do:

```
/user/plugins/*
!/user/plugins/.gitkeep
!/user/plugins/google-photos/
```

Meaning: you need to whitelist folders first, before being able to exclude from gitignore files.

Double-check with [`git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) to confirm it is working as expected

Comment: now that your question is edited, this remaining comment could be misleading. perhaps delete it completely?