# why git is ignoring my files?

Tags: git, github, yii2

I am trying to install Yii2 php on openshift, first installed on openshift from github, then, pulled it to my local repo. When I add a file to my local repo, `git add .` lists it successfully. But when I add a new folder, it does not. 
after googling for an hour, tried this command,

```
 git status -uall --ignored
```

and found that my changes are being ignored.
now can't find the .gitignore file due to which git is ignoring my files.
also Used windows CLI command dir/ad etc. then tried this...

```
$ find ~/ -type f -name ".gitignore" -print
```

found too many .gitignore files in multiple directories. but none of them was in my working directory.

read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144633/which-gitignore-rule-is-ignoring-my-file) thread and researched more for an hour.. still no luck!

Why is git ignoring my newly added folders?

Comment: Are the newly added folders *empty*?

Comment: no they have multiple files and folders in them.

Comment: it says nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: And what is the result of `git add -A`?

Comment: still nothing to commit working directory clean

Comment: And the folders exist? You mention you're on windows, check the folder permissions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107363/discussion-between-ramesh-pareek-and-elliott-frisch).

Comment: What happens when you try to add a specific named file in one of the ignored subdirectories? `git add ignored_directory/specific_file.txt`? What does `git status` show after having done that?

Comment: yes it exists. this folder should not have permissions. I don't want this folder to be web accessible.

Comment: as I said there is no .gitignore file in my working directory. I'll add one and then tell you the output in a minute.

Comment: oh thanks. .. discovered it. it was a .gitignore file, windows was hiding its name. when i created new .gitignore, the new file was created without a name. then i thought of the no-named files, opened up and found the entry for the folder.