# gitignore allow certain file only in named subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

I am currently cleaning up a git-repository, moving dependencies and so on.
I have decided to have a global folder which contains all third-party libraries that we use. Except for these `*.dll` files, I want to ignore any other dll-Files in the project.

So my `gitignore` in the root directory of the project contains these lines:

```
*.dll
!external\ libraries/*.dll
```

Which apparently does not work.
I also tried placing a .gitignore file into the `external libraries` directory, containing the line `!*.dll`, which did not work either.

What am I doing wrong?

e/

Output of ls in `external libraries`

```
/external libraries (branchname)
$ ls
file1.dll*
file2.dll*
```

In the root directory *ls* returns all folders as expected.

Comment: i guess all other dll are in a bin folder, so ignore "bin\*.dll", does it resolve your issue?

AFAIK with "!" you can only specifify a single file or folder not to be ignored.

Comment: Weird, but this seems to work when I tried to reproduce your problem. Can you share the output of `ls` in your relevant directories?

Comment: I ignored the bin folder now  @TomSöhne and removed any other ignores of dll files. I even refreshed the cache of the gitignore but those files still do not show up on `git status`

Comment: I edited into the question @Mureinik

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://pastebin.com/MSJcF2st

Comment: To find out which rule is actually ignoring the files, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12168102/1615903

Comment: @1615903 Checking which file blocks the dlls helped me out, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked via `git check-ignore -v filename` how the file was blocked and apparently at some point a global gitignore file was created on my computer. Deleting it resolved my problem.