# Gitignore a folder from vendor folder in Symfony

Tags: git, symfony, gitignore

I want to not ignore a folder in vendor in my Symfony app. I put in .gitignore:

```
!/vendor/
/vendor/*
!/vendor/myfolder-one/myfolder-two
```

But this don't work? What is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be *ignoring* the whole vendor directory anyways?

Comment: I vendor directory I have a bundle and I want to not ignore this.

Comment: Maybe you can just remove the first line in your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Don't work with remove the line `!/vendor/`

Comment: related and useful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12144633/1256452 ("which gitignore rule is ignoring my file")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something in your bundle ( I assume it is somewhere on git repo and You have it as dependency in composer ) try to run `composer install --prefer-source`. Then You can make changes in your bundle and push them to it's repo from within your project.