# How to reliably check whether a file is ignored by git?

Tags: git, bash, gitignore

I'm encountering a problem where `git check-ignore` is not respecting `.gitignore`'s 'not' (`!`) rules. It's returning "Ignored" if a file matches any entry in the `.gitignore` file, regardless of whether that entry is telling it to not ignore the path (via the `!` operator)

[`git check-ignore`'s documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) states the return codes map as follows:

> **EXIT STATUS**
>
> - **0**: One or more of the provided paths is ignored.
> - **1**: None of the provided paths are ignored.
> - **128**: A fatal error was encountered.

This doesn't match what I'm seeing when I add "Do not ignore" rules, i.e. sticking `!` in front of an entry.

As an example, let's create a file structure as follows:

```
.gitignore
files/
    path-not-ignored
ignored-files/
    path-ignored
    path-not-ignored
```

and a `.gitignore` containing:

```
ignored-files/*
!ignored-files/path-not-ignored
```

According to the documentation, I'd expect the files in `files/` and `ignored-files/path-not-ignored` to return exit status 1 (not ignored), and `ignored-files/path-is-ignored` to return 0 (ignored).

What I'm seeing instead of everything in `ignored-files` returning exit status 0 (ignored):

```
File                             | Expected exit status | Actual exit status | Summary
-------------------------------- | -------------------- | ------------------ | -------
`files/path-not-ignored`         | 1 (Not ignored)      | 1 (Not ignored)    | Expected
`ignored-files/path-ignored`     | 0 (Ignored)          | 0 (Ignored)        | Expected
`ignored-files/path-not-ignored` | 1 (Not ignored)      | 0 (Ignored)        | Unexpected
```

(Exit status codes are being checked with `git check-ignore <file>;echo $?`)

This doesn't match Git's internal behaviour, because I can `git add add ignored-files/path-not-ignored` just fine:

```
File                             | `git add`?                   | Matches `git check-ignore` output?
-------------------------------- | ---------------------------- | ----------------------------------
`files/path-not-ignored`         | Adds file (as expected)      | Yes
`ignored-files/path-ignored`     | Throws warning (as expected) | Yes
`ignored-files/path-not-ignored` | Adds file (as expected)      | No


git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   files/path-not-ignored
    new file:   ignored-files/path-not-ignored

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitignore
```

---

As `git check-ignore` is unreliable in this case, are there any other commands I could use to check whether Git is ignoring / not ignoring a given file?

Something that returns exit codes would be ideal, as I'm using this in a bash script.

Comment: One option might be to use `git add --dry-run`.  It's unfortunate that Git has this bug though... it looks like there's code that should be handling the negation, but I bet it's not working correctly with the globbing.

Comment: Hmmm... looking at the man page, I'm not sure that it's behaving badly given the subject ("Debug gitignore / exclude files").  OTOH, given the documented return values I'd say it is behaving badly.  I'll enquire on the git list about this.

Comment: It looks like this is an issue, though the -q option may be needed to invoke the exit status. The -v -n options can help debug if the ignore order matters, and multiple paths can be given to split out the cases.

Comment: The tests of git-check-ignore that are in the git repo are all in [\git\t\t0008-ignores.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t0008-ignores.sh) (all 845 lines)

Comment: Junio responded saying that he believes check-ignore started out as a [debugging aid](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=150092424004428&w=2) (rather than a way to check if a file is ignored).  So using it this way is not its original intent.  If you're willing to parse the output of a `git status` call, you could consider using `git status --ignored --porcelain <filename>` and looking for `!!` at the beginning of the line.  Not sure how that would work with directories.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144633/which-gitignore-rule-is-ignoring-my-file (2012 - 2016) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore (2009 - 2012).  The (2017) git mailing list discussion is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466764/git-command-to-show-which-specific-files-are-ignored-by-gitignore. Sounds like it's an 'open' problem for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the issue persists since July 2017 with Git 2.18 (July 2018).

[Commit d60771e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d60771e93046e9e11183c6ff1fcafd334f8c0453) might have helped remove false positive.

> ### `check-ignore`: fix mix of directories and other file types
>
> In `check_ignore()`, the first pathspec item determines the dtype for any
> subsequent ones.
> That means that a pathspec matching a regular file can prevent following pathspecs from matching directories, which makes no sense.