# Using .gitignore with *.pyc in subfolders

Tags: python, git, gitignore

I see that with python 3, there is a __pycache__ in each subfolder of my application and of course *.pyc files will be created there as well.  In my .gitignore of my app's root folder, can I simply place:

```
**/__pycache__
**/*.pyc
```

to have these ignored in all future subfolders created?  Or do I need to place a .gitignore in each and every subfolder ?

On a related note, how do I check what all is being untracked (ignored). I tried "git status -u" and it does not show __pycache__ or .pyc files as being untracked.

Comment: To see if a file is ignored, and if so, why, use `git check-ignore -v`. Note that a file that is already in the index is tracked, regardless of whether it might match a `.gitignore` directive; see the `--no-index` option as well. The `git check-ignore` command first appeared in Git version 1.8.2.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should not need the `**/`:

```
 __pycache__/
 *.pyc
```

That should be enough.

See for instance [gitignore.io/python](https://www.gitignore.io/api/python).
Note the practice of adding a trailing `/` to ignore specifically a folder.

Use `git check-ignore -v -- afile` (that [I mentioned in Sept. 2013, with Git 1.8.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18953923/6309)) to check which rule ignores a file.
If the folder was already tracked:

```
git rm --cached -r __pycache__/
```

---

[André Duarte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980803/andr%C3%A9-duarte) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587096/using-gitignore-with-pyc-in-subfolders/51587124#comment102849252_51587124):

> After adjusting `gitignore`, I had to do this for every file, so I call `awk` for help:
>
> ```
> git status | grep pycache | awk '{print $3}' | xargs git reset HEAD
> ```

Comment: After adjust gitignore, I had to do this  for every file, so I call awk for help: "git status | grep pycache | awk {'print $3'} | xargs git reset HEAD"

Comment: I still have those __pycache__  under the subfolders exist. not sure why? And when I run git check-ignore -v, I got an error fatal: no path specified.

Comment: @GLP `git check-ignore -v` is supposed to be followed by a path: `git check-ignore -v -- path/to/pycache/a/file`: that way, you can check if a .gitignore rule applies to any file in a `pycache` folder.