# git ignoring something that shouldn't be ignored

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I noticed any change I make in one of my scripts (in a Unity3D application) does not appear in my `SourceTree` or `git bash` command line.

I checked my `gitignore` file to see if I might have added a keyword that exists somewhere in the path to the file, but I cannot seem to find anything that would explain why this script is being ignored...

This is the path: `D:\Dropbox\Agents\Avatars\Unity_Projects\Avatar1\Assets\BlendShapePresetTool\Demo\Scripts\Demo.cs`

Other than the `gitignore` file, what could possibly be the reason for something not being tracked, even though the whole project is being tracked?

*p.s.* When I added the `BlendShapePresetTool` plug-in, I did add everything, hence my confusion...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain which gitignore rule is ignoring my file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144633/explain-which-gitignore-rule-is-ignoring-my-file)

Comment: Check the duplicate suggestion : there is a `git check-ignore` command to check if a file is ignored, and which rule excludes it from versioning (with `-v`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comments you can use this command:

```
# print out list of ignored patterns 
git check-ignore *

# add the -v to see where the ignored patters is defined
git check-ignore * -v
```

[image]