Why is Git ignoring one of my source files?
A file in my Visual Studio project was not being checked into the repository. On closer inspection, I can see this file is flagged as Ignored.

On further investigation, I found the following section at the very end of my .gitignore file.
# BeatPulse healthcheck temp database
healthchecksdb
/PegasusReportBuilders/Builders/MaverickTrucksReportBuilder.cs

This was causing the problem. But can anyone say what has happened here? What is healthchecksdb? And why would it be adding files to the ignore list.

It's not evident to me that healthchecksdb is responsible for this.  An errant click which accidentally led to adding the file to .gitignore would certainly cause this.  Perhaps the source control history on .gitignore can shed some light on when it happened and who added it?  Ultimately it sounds like the problem was simply a mistake in that file and has been solved...

Is this MaverickTrucksReportBuilder.cs file autogenerated?

@David: It was resolved after I deleted this selection. Yeah, I thought about it being me clicking somewhere on accident. But I don't know where that would be. Am not seeing a menu command or anything that would cause this.

@EugeneSh. No, it's one of my source files.

@JonathanWood: That's the thing about errant clicks, they could happen anywhere.  Maybe in a context menu/sub-menu on the file in the solution explorer, maybe on a context menu/sub-menu in a Git explorer, maybe while adding/committing/stashing/whatevering in any previous Git operation which involved that file, etc., etc.  Honestly this sounds like a bit of a wild goose chase.  The mistake was found and corrected.  The source control history for .gitignore can tell you when it was added and who added it, but it can't tell you where that person clicked or what command they used.

You can test if it's a gitignore problem with https://stackoverflow.com/a/12168102/1043380


What is healthchecksdb?

Something unrelated that just happened to be at the bottom of the .gitignore file.

can anyone say what has happened here?

You clicked this or something similar by accident

It's also available via the tab name, and probably other places.

Yes, something like that. However, I tried clicking that menu command and that results in a different icon shown left of the file (a red circle with an X instead of a minus).
